# Adding a feature from a dataset into a function causes "TypeError: can't convert type 'ndarray' to numerator/denominator"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset, linear-regression

The task requires you to load a feature of the diabetes dataset and write your own line of best fit for the training data.

I have written the required line of best fit algorithm, however when trying to add the training data to it, I receive this error:

"TypeError: can't convert type 'ndarray' to numerator/denominator"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from statistics import mean

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
diabetes_X = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 2]

diabetes_X_train = diabetes_X[:-20] #creating the testing and training data 
diabetes_X_test = diabetes_X[-20:]

diabetes_y_train = diabetes.target[:-20]
diabetes_y_test = diabetes.target[-20:]

## The below code is where the issue is occurring 

xs = np.array(diabetes_X_train, dtype=np.float64)
ys = np.array([diabetes_y_train, dtype=np.float64)

##the algorithm to calculate the line of best  

def best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs,ys):
    m = (((mean(xs)*mean(ys)) - mean(xs*ys)) /
         ((mean(xs)*mean(xs)) - mean(xs*xs)))

    b = mean(ys) - m*mean(xs)

    return m, b

m, b = best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs,ys)

print(m,b)
```

I understand converting the required data into the correct format is the issue but after doing research, I am unable to find the correct way to do so.

All input on how to correctly concatenate or convert the training data as required is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the best format for dealing with data is DataFrame, in my view.
you could easily make your dataframe like this:

```
urdataframe={'headername': bestfitted}
urdataframe=pd.DataFrames(data=urdataframe)
```

then you can contact ur dataframes easily like :

```
finaldata=pd.concat((traindata,urdataframe),axis=1)
```

you could do all machine learning functions on DataFrames and less likely to get errors

Comment: Thank you,

Could you add some further context? IE what exactly would get concatenated in your second piece of code.

Comment: you're welcome! if it's not the answer you were looking for, you need to give extra information

Answer (score 0):

for example, if ur train data is something like:
age   sex   sugar
42    1      120
45    0      250
32    1      98

and your answer is like:
answer
yes
no
yes

so after contact by the code, I mentioned it would be like:
age   sex   sugar    answer
42    1      120     yes
45    0      250     no
32    1      98      yes